# HR (vertical line) stretches the rest of the table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an Email Signature Generator. I am trying to get the blue line (it can be seen in the program) to stretch all the way down. However, when I do it, it stretches the rest of the items. I believe this may be because it is all inside a table and when one element is sized differently than the others, it tries it equal it out but I am not sure how to change it. Here is my code:

```css
table {
  display: inline-block;
}

#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.spacer {
  width: 30px;
}

hr {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
}

#fullName {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: orange;
}

#job {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 11px;
}

#jobLocationText {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id="image">
    </td>
    <td class="spacer"></td>
    <td>
      <hr>
    </td>
    <td class="spacer"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <div id="fullName">Billy Staples</div>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <div id="job"><i>Programmer</i></div>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <div id="jobLocationText">at the <b id="jobLocation">HTML hub</b></div>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And a working version can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/CyanCoding/he84kv8n/9/).

Again, I am trying to get it so the hr (in the CSS) when the height is changed (to say 300 or something) it doesn't stretch the rest of the table with it. If you have an idea as to how I might be able to do my table differently so that it might be easier or just so that I could fix this problem, suggestions are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `rowspan=""` to strech `<hr>` to way down,

```
<td rowspan="4">
  <hr>
</td>
```

Here's your updated code, https://jsfiddle.net/he84kv8n/10/

Answer (score 0):

`<hr>` is a *horizontal* rule (divider), bending it to be a *vertical* rule (divider) is a use case that will likely be difficult for anyone looking at your code to decipher.

I would suggest using a CSS border attribute on the table cell, that will automatically be the correct size.